# Problema de inserción de datos a tabla cuya columna es de tipo Image

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de escritorio [windows-forms](/questions/tagged/windows-forms) que inserta registros de una tabla a otra tabla que se encuentra en otra base de datos.

Ejemplo: La información de la tabla `UserFinger` que está en la base de datos `BD_Cliente` se insertará en otra tabla llamada `UserFinger` en otra base de datos llamada `BD_Servidor`.

Ambas tablas son idénticas en estructura y las bases de datos son las mismas *(exceptuando que `BD_Servidor` puede tener mas tablas, pero esto no interfiere con el propósito de esta pregunta)*.

Esta es la estructura de la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserFinger](
    [Userid] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Fingerid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FPTemplate] [image] NULL
)
```

Estos son algunos datos de muestra que posee la tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por código estoy realizando estos pasos:

- Consulto la información de la tabla `UserFinger` de la base de datos `BD_Cliente` y almaceno los resultados en una variable de tipo `DataTable`.
- Recorro las filas de la variable de tipo `DataTable` para armar la instrucción `INSERT INTO UserFinger`.

Al examinar la información de la variable `DataTable` tengo estos valores:

[image: DataTable con datos de UserFinger]

Estoy armando la instrucción `INSERT INTO` de esta manera<sup>1</sup>:

```
// Recorrer los registros del DataTable.
foreach (DataRow fila in tbl.Rows)
{
    // Armar la instrucción SQL de tipo INSERT:
    sql_cmd = " INSERT INTO UserFinger (Userid, Fingerid, FPTemplate) " +
              " VALUES ('" + fila["Userid"].ToString() + "', " + fila["Fingerid"].ToString() + ", '" + fila["FPTemplate"].ToString() + "')";

    // Ejecutar instrucción SQL.
    EjecutarSQL(GetConnectionStringSQL_Cloud(), "UserFinger", sql_cmd);
}
```

El problema que tengo es que el valor de `fila["FPTemplate"].ToString()` es `System.Byte[]`.

¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor de `System.Byte[]` para almacenar correctamente el valor?, es decir, ¿para guardar `0x0E099394210C0D9381119D55C1149129C...`?

He intentado usar:

[Fuente: Convert a byte array in a datatable column to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4242568/4092887)

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString((byte[])fila["FPTemplate"])
```

Y similares resultados de búsqueda, pero de 146 resultados que posee la tabla `UserFinger` de base de datos llamada `BD_Cliente`, solo ingresa 65 en la tabla de la base de datos llamada `BD_Servidor`; esto es porque no reconoce las caracteres como caracteres Unicode válidos o `(según el log de eventos de mi aplicación)` dice:

- Error: Incorrect syntax near '?'.
  The identifier that starts with ':?V?L??Q???V   ?B00..................................000000..................................000000..............................' is too long. Maximum length is 128.
- Error: 'u??u?*?................ .    "' is an invalid name because it contains a NULL character or an invalid unicode character.

**Edito**

Gracias a la [respuesta del usuario José Rolando](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/198006/78), hice la prueba con el código proporcionado y se solucionan (los errores mencionados), pero a pesar de registrar los 146 registros, todos los valores de `FPTemplate` son iguales.

No sé porqué se da esto, pero, seguí buscando en internet y [encontré](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/28daf8b7-0308-427f-87e2-6d6e09d93279/display-byte-array-in-a-string?forum=csharpgeneral) que al usar `BitConverter` se obtiene un resultado *similar al origen de datos*.

Estos son los resultados *luego* de usar `BitConverter`:

[image: Ejemplo usando BitConverter]

Si se hace la comparación de datos del Userid `106` se puede ver que son ligeramente diferentes.

Ejemplo de la tabla `UserFinger` de `BD_Servidor` - *mirar la columna `FPTemplate`* -:

[image: Resultados en la tabla destino]

Mientras que en la tabla de `UserFinger` de `BD_Cliente`, *el valor de la columna `FPTemplate`* es:

[image: Resultados de la tabla origen]

¿Cómo puedo registrar correctamente el valor de la tabla tabla de `UserFinger` de `BD_Cliente` a la tabla de `UserFinger` de `BD_Servidor`?

Me pregunto si esto influye en la lectura ya que - si no me equivoco - este campo guarda una plantilla de la huella digital, por lo que busco que los datos a guardar en la `BD_Servidor` sean los mismos que los almacenados en `BD_Cliente`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Se que no es buena práctica armar instrucciones así, pero para efectos de lo que necesito, así es como estoy abordando este desarrollo.

Answer (score 0):

en realidad el problema no está en la base de datos, sino en la conversión del tipo de datos en el winform, Con el siguiente código podrás convertir los datos de la base de datos en bytes para luego guardarlas nuevamente en la base de datos:

```
(byte[])drItem("fingerid")();
```

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta. Lo intenté, pero, a pesar de hacer la inserción de los 146 registros, todos los valores de `FPTemplate` son iguales. [Esta es una imagen de los resultados](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5bKB.png).